# How can I view iWork documents on my android device?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, chrome-for-android

Is there a way to view (even better would be to edit) iWork documents on Android. I'm particularly interested in Pages, but there is also Numbers and Keynotes, all of them are part of Apple's iWork suite.

Also, in [this page](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT206181) they say I should be able to do that from a web browser signing in to iCloud.com, but then a page is shown saying that my browser is not supported. I have Chrome 58.0.3029.83 running on KitKat 4.4.2

Comment: Doesn't it work if you open that site with your browser in *desktop mode*?

Comment: @beeshyams I was able to login, it shows a message saying "Your browser isn't fully supported", also can see the thumbnail of the document but it won't open.

Comment: Oh. It was a try. Well, Apple  says you can't, as you can see [ here](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201484)- so Android isn't supported , sorry. Nor is there any app per my search that can overcome this  , so the smart is that you can't

Comment: @beeshyams I see... they need to update the info on the link I found.